# Com knockoutjs fazer um CheckBox com comportamento de Radiobutton

Tags: knockoutjs

Bom já fiz uma pergunta tentei todos os código que me foi passando e nada, e foi marcado como duplicada, Porém como pode ser visto no código abaixo não funciona como desejado.

```js
function DemoItem(id, name) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.associatedItemIds = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function () {
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five'));
    };
    
    self.toggleAssociation = function (item) {
        if (item.Selected() === true) console.log("dissociate item " + item.id());
        else console.log("associate item " + item.id());
        item.Selected(!(item.Selected()));
        return true;
    };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();

function marcaDesmarca(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');    
  for(let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    checks[i].checked = checks[i] == caller;   
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Available Items:
<table data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: $root.associatedItemIds, click: $root.toggleAssociation"  onclick="marcaDesmarca(this)"/> 
    <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
    </td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
Associated Item Ids:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.associatedItemIds">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

No meu código estou tentando dessa maneira mas ainda está com erro:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.isSelected = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                    $(element).checked = false;

                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                    if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                        //Desmarca os demais checkbox que estão na mesma tabela que o checkbox clicado
                        $(element).closest('table').find(':checkbox').not(element).prop('checked', false);
                        //Atribui o valor 0 para o select que esteja na mesma tabela que o checkbox clicado
                        $(element).closest('table').find('select').prop('value', 0);
                    }
                }
            };
```